# Discord.js "undefined". How do I remove the undefined in my embed command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I used the code below and I got this result. I don't know how to remove the "undefined" can you provide me with a better code or revise my code?

[image]

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '?welcomemsg') {
    const MessageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FF0000')
      .addField(`*Welcome to PhyZics Public Discord! We created this server so in order for us to stay connected to our grinders and our to our community members.*`)
      .addField('\u200b')
      .addField(`*PhyZics is a community and team created to recongnize small players and grinders that have the potential to play for our team.*`)
      .setFooter('PhyZics Management Team; PhyZics Bot powered by Jun');
    message.channel.send(MessageEmbed);
  }
});
```

Comment: In which field does `undefined` appear? Can you send the screenshot of the message?

Comment: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/727673785028837462/729383148634374224/Annotation_2020-07-05_125923.png?width=272&height=131

Comment: @JunXC that embed is not from this code, this code does not have a title but the embed in the image does, could you please post the right code?

Comment: I think this one is it
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/727673785028837462/729387063593533530/Annotation_2020-07-05_125923.png

Answer (score 1):

**You're misusing the `addField` method.**
According to [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField), you need a title, **and** description inside all of your fields, like so :

```js
MessageEmbed.addField('Your cool title', 'An even cooler description !')
```

After seeing your code, I think that the [setDescription](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setDescription) method would be better for what you're trying to achieve.
This would make your final embed look like this:

```js
const MessageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FF0000')
      .setDescription(`*Welcome to PhyZics Public Discord! We created this server so in order for us to stay connected to our grinders and our to our community members.* \n*PhyZics is a community and team created to recognize small players and grinders that have the potential to play for our team.*`)
      .setFooter('PhyZics Management Team; PhyZics Bot powered by Jun');
message.channel.send(MessageEmbed);
```

Please note the usage of the `\n` character, which creates a line break inside of your description.
Doing the following would result in the exact same thing :

```js
setDescription(`
*Welcome to PhyZics Public Discord! We created this server so in order for us to stay connected to our grinders and our to our community members.*
*PhyZics is a community and team created to recognize small players and grinders that have the potential to play for our team.*
`)
```

I hope that I have answered all of your questions, and that this will help you to fix your issue ! :)

Comment: Darn, beat me to it!

Comment: @AlpacaFur hehe, I'll leave you the next one ;P

Comment: @JunXC happy I could have helped :3 by the way, welcome to StackOverflow ! Make sure to mark the answer as valid by clicking on the small check to let others know that your question has already been answered !